# JFrame vs Container

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, containers

I read that the window that appears using the `JFrame` class is a `Container` with the predefined features (minimize, closing), but I found people who were not using the `JFrame` class but other classes (one of them the `Container`) which was far more hard.

Why do they do it that way? Is it because the `JFrame` class always has a predefined window that you can manipulate some aspects of it but the `Container` and the other classes give you more freedom of how you can create a window?

For an example to my question (I don't know if its real or not) in the `JFrame` class the close button always go to right to corner of the window but if I do it the other way you can put it everywhere you like. (If it can be answered with a yes or no).

Comment: We cannot explain why people unknown to us wrote code we cannot examine in the way they did.  Moreover, although `JFrame` is not the only top-level container, `Container` itself is not one, so I'm inclined to think that you are misinterpreting at least some of what you saw.

Comment: Overall, questions about people's motivations are rarely on-topic here.  I suggest having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking for information on what you *can* ask, and on how you should frame your questions for the greatest likelihood of a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

> So my qusetion is why they do it that way

There are two "main" reasons why.  First is about overall good programming.

We tend to recommend avoiding extending from classes to which we are not adding any new functionality or repeatable features.  If the whole reason for extending from `JFrame` is just so you can display some components, then it's really not a good choice or starting point.

`JFrame` is also a complex, compound component.  That is, it's actually made up of a number of other layered components which work together to provide an overall experience.

[image: RootPane]

*From [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

This means that there is a lot of added complexity you'd have to be willing to manage if you extended from this class, a lot of overhead just to display a few components.

In principle, it's better to use composition over inheritance, which leads into the second point.

Extending from any class locks you into that classes use case.  In the case of `JFrame`, you can only ever display what ever is managed by the class via a `JFrame`, there is no flexibility or entry point for re-usablility.

If, instead, you started with a base class of, say `JPanel`, you can add that to what ever container you want when ever you want, it increases the flexibility and re-usability of the class over all.

> For an exaple to my question(i dont know if its real or not) in the JFrame class the close button always go to right to corner of the window but if i do it the other way you can put it everywhere you like.(If it can be answered with a yes or no)

Yes and no.  The frame border is defined by the look and feel delegate, so you're not actually starting at the right place to begin with anyway.

Most look and feel delegates delegate the frame border to the native platform, in the case of Windows, yes, the close button is on the right, on Mac it's on the left.

In any case, it's better to support user expectations, placing the close button in an unusual place might make the UI "pretty", but diminishes the user experience - as a general guide line, don't diminish the user experience, no matter how awesome your program or UI, user's won't like you for it - but that is a (very broad) question for another day